# Angular Form Validation using Ng Model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation, angularjs-ng-form

**Question: How can I show the validation error using only the `ng-model` if I cannot name the form and its elements.**

I have a html form to collect credit card details. To prevent the credit card data from touching my server, I cannot name the form elements. So my form looks like:

```
<form ng-submit="vm.processForm()">

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" ng-model="vm.number" required>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month" ng-model="vm.exp_month" required>
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year" ng-model="vm.exp_year" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" ng-model="vm.cvc" required>
    </label>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
</form>
```

Usually in Angular, I used to check validation using the form elements name, for example like this:

```
<p ng-show="userForm.creditcard.$error.required">Your credit card number is required.</p>
```

But since I cannot name the form and its elements, how can I show the validation error using only the ng-model? Because, the following doesn't work:

```
<p ng-show="vm.number.$error.required">Your credit card number is required.</p>
```

I am using Angular v1.4.8.

Comment: <p ng-show="form.$submitted && !vm.number">Blabla</p>

Comment: Oh yeah, good idea. Can I use a similar way for `maxlength` and `minlength `validation?

Comment: Well, sure. You can check if vm.number.length > x. However this is wrong. Why can't you use names and validate the way it's meant to be?

Comment: `vm.number.length` should work. Simple, but it did not strike me. The reason I can't use names because adding name would make the user-supplied data in those fields to be passed to my server when the form is submitted. I dont want that since not naming means I no longer need to worry about redacting logs, encrypting cardholder details, or other burdens of PCI compliance.

Comment: If you can add this as the answer, I can accept it and close this. Thank you kindly for replying.

Comment: Submitted to where? If you don't have an "action" attribute in your form.

Comment: It will be submitted to stripe server directly for further processing.

Comment: The form will be sent to stripe like this `Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);` which creates a token for that card, and then only the card token gets saved in my server.

Comment: ng-submit doesn't send anything anywhere. It just calls the function you put in it. The form data is in the ng-model attributes you have in each input. I don't see how names are a problem. Anyway....

Comment: hmm... it makes sense what you are saying. When I read the stripe documentation for custom forms, it said the name attribute will make the card data touch my server. But thinking about it, that is probably is the case with action script. Right now in angular, ng-submit just send the form objects to stripe server first to get the token and then process the token with my server. So name or no name, the cc data shouldnt be touching my server anyways. I think you are right there. Thank you for pointing it out. The stripe doc I read is from here: https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a directive to export de the model controller. I don't think that is the best way but it works.

```
.directive('exportModel', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
        attr.$observe('exportModel', function (value) {
        scope[value] = ngModel;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11352/